# Объясните, почему код не работает

Tags: python, функции

Дана задача:

> Вновь велогонщики собрались узнать, кто из них быстрее. Им предстоит
> пройти трассу длиной 43872м, и нам нужно вновь определить победителя.
>
> На этот раз нам известны средние скорости трёх фаворитов — Пети, Васи
> и Толи. Кто из них пришёл к финишу первым?
>
> Формат ввода: В первой строке записана средняя скорость Пети. Во второй
> — Васи. В третьей — Толи.
>
> Формат вывода: Имя победителя гонки.
>
> Примечание: Гарантируется, что победителем стал только один.

Написал к ней вот такой код на Python:

```
petya_speed = int(input())
vasya_speed = int(input())
tolya_speed = int(input())

max_speed = max(petya_speed, vasya_speed, tolya_speed)

def winner(speed):
    match speed:
        case 1 if speed == petya_speed: print('Петя')
        case 2 if speed == vasya_speed: print('Вася')
        case 3 if speed == tolya_speed: print('Толя')

print(winner(max_speed))
```

Однако он не работает и выводит None. Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: Вы строки в функцию max пихаете? И что вам функция max возвращает?

Comment: @Александр вроде он там `int(` делает, не?

Comment: Но он то в winner передаёт имена, нет?

Comment: Вы бы код сначала посмотрели потом меня поправляли.

Comment: Я не пойму контекст использования функции max.

Comment: In [1]: name = "Alexandr"

In [2]: result = max(name)

In [3]: result
Out[3]: 'x'

Comment: @Александр я переменную глупо назвал, извиняюсь, сначала я нахожу максимальную среднюю скорость среди трех фаворитов, а потом написал функцию winner которая на вход получает эту скорость и ищет того у кого из фаворитов она есть

Comment: Господин kollontai, посмотрите что вы вытворяете.

Comment: Из контекста задачи я понимаю что вам нужно сделать, но так как вы глупо делаете, то у меня не получится вам пояснить, в чём вы именно ошибаетесь.

Comment: @Александр в winner передается максимальное значение (а не имя), а вот потом `match case` просто неправильно используется

Comment: Kromster, вы умный а я по вашему глуп?) Я вообще-то веду диалог с автором вопроса а не с вами.

Comment: Изменил названия переменных, чтобы код был понятным

Comment: Сделайте лучше без match case, здесь оно не к месту

Comment: @MBo я написал уже к ней код с помощью условных операторов, но не могу понять почему не работает при помощи match

Comment: Ок, понятно, только семантика этого процесса нелогичная. Сначала вы теряете связь значения с переменной в Макс, потом восстанавливаете соответствие в матч.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы решить эту проблему нужно:

1. Функция должна возвращать не `print('Петя')` и т.п., а саму строку `'Петя'`;
2. Нужно использовать другие имена переменных в `case` блоках, например, добавить к ним префиксы;

В итоге, код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
petya = int(input())
vasya = int(input())
tolya = int(input())

best = max(petya, vasya, tolya)

def winner(name):
    match name:
        case x if x == petya: return 'Петя'
        case x if x == vasya: return 'Вася'
        case x if x == tolya: return 'Толя'


print(winner(best))
```

Comment: Тогда уж без `match` будет проще. `if name == petya: return 'Петя'` - повторить три раза.